# Javascript/jQuery: Replace Text in Single Quotes with HTML span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a string like this:

```
This is a 'item:value' and another 'item2:value:2'.
```

I want to use Javascript/jQuery to get the following result:

```
This is a <span class="text">item:value</span> and another <span class="text">item2:value:2</span>.
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help docs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to ask a good question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if my answer is what you are going for.  If it isn't please state the question a little clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a regex `replace()` on the text between the single quotes:

```
 var str = "This is a 'item:value' and another 'item2:value:2'."

 var newString = str.replace(/'(.*?)'/g, function myFunction(x){
    x = "<span class='text'>"+ x +"</span>"
    return x;
 })
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ce1qm0za/

Answer (score 0):

use concatination:

```
 $("div").html('This is a <span class="text">' + item + ':' + value + '</span> and another <span class="text">' + item2 + ':' + value2 + '</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var string = "This is a 'item:value' and another 'item2:value:2'.";
    var res = string.split("'");
    var output = res[0] + "<span class='text'>" + res[1] + "</span>" + res[2] + "<span class='text'>" + res[3] + "</span>" + res[4] ; 
    console.log(output);
</script>
```

Hope this is what you meant.